# Update from OS X Lion 10.7.5 to macOS Mojave 10.14

Tags: macos, mojave, software-update

I have recently got a mid 2012 Macbook Air which I installed Lion on. I am trying to update it to Mojave, but even though it is compatible, when downloading it in the App Store I get this error message:

[image: error message]

How can I upgrade my Mac to Mojave? Do I need to upgrade to OS X 10.8 first?

Comment: Related, though not a dupe - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer to this macOS upgrade instructions webpage, (currently it refers to macOS Mojave):

- [macOS - How to Upgrade](https://www.apple.com/macos/how-to-upgrade/)

> **Upgrading from OS X Snow Leopard or Lion**
>
> If you’re running Snow Leopard (10.6.8) or Lion (10.7) and your Mac supports macOS Mojave, you will need to upgrade to El Capitan (10.11) first. Click [here](https://support.apple.com/HT206886) for instructions.

Comment: Here's a direct link to [El Capitan page on App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/app/os-x-el-capitan/id1147835434?ls=1&mt=12) (on the page you provided).